# Is there any trick I can use to handle SVG imports in my non-Webpack-using test code?

Tags: javascript, testing, webpack

I have a Webpack-using codebase with lines like the following:

```
import Foo from './svg/icons/foo.svg';
```

and because of `svg-react-loader` it works.

However, using Webpack in our test environment would slow things down and add some headaches, so we run our tests (in Node) without it.  This worked great up until we started importing SVGs like the one above, at which point we started to get errors like:

```
ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/projects/foo/src/svg/icons/foo.svg:1:1)
```

(which I'm pretty sure happens because Node thinks the SVG file, which is made up of XML and thus looks like JSX, should be handled by React).

So, I realize one solution would be to run our test environment through Webpack, but my question is, is there any way to make:

```
import Foo from './svg/icons/foo.svg';
```

not fail (or at least fail silently and keep going) when my non-Webpack test code runs it?  For instance, is there anyway I could "shim" the Node loader so that if it sees a `.svg` it just moves along without doing anything?